# Determine stability of the fixed points of $\dot x=x-x^3$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find all of the fixed points of the system $\dot x=x-x^3$, and determine whether they are stable or unstable (or neither). Make sketches of at least 2 solutions of this system (corresponding to different initial values) which converge to different values at t goes to infinity.

Ok, so I am a little confused about what this question is asking. I just starting a class called Qualitative Ordinary Differential Equations and he never went over a problem like this. I am assuming that I can do $f(x)=x(1-x^2)$ so $2$ solutions would be $x=0$ and $x=1$, but for sure reason I feel like I need to integrate or take a derivative or something.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Do you know what a phase line is?

Comment: I have no idea what that is. This is my first week of class.

Comment: [Phase line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_line_(mathematics))

Comment: Draw a picture! The state space is $\mathbb{R}$ so you can guess by drawing the function $f(x) = x-x^3$ and noting where it is zero, positive and negative...

Comment: So when would it be stable or unstable?

Comment: @Brian The Wiki article explains how to determine stability after drawing the phase line.

Answer (score 1):

The set $F = \{0, 1, -1\}$ contains all the fixed points of your system.

To consider the stability of the points, we need to look at a neighborhood of each element in $F.$ This is just a fancy way of saying, we are going to test some points.

Break this up into $4$ intervals.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} \hline \text{Interval} & \text{Sign of $x'$} & \text{Direction of arrows}  \\ \hline (-\infty, -1)& + & \text{up}\\ \hline (-1,0)  & -& \text{down}\\ \hline (0,1) & +& \text{up} \\ \hline (1,\infty) & -&\text{down} \\ \hline  \end{array}

Put all those cases together and we conclude that $x = \pm1$ are stable, and
$x = 0$ is a unstable point. The last two points are also commonly called repellers and attractors respectively.

Comment: Thank you that helps a ton

Comment: Hope this helps you draw the sketches.